# Google Form data not using my preset conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, conditional-formatting

I have just made a Google Form and linked it to a Google Sheets, I already went through and set conditional formatting on the sheet but, when someone fills out the Form the data goes to my Sheet but the data doesn't format is there a way to lock this so when data from a form can auto format without me trying to manually color code everything?

Comment: "is there a way to lock this so when data from a form can auto format without me trying to manually color code everything?"  Yes, there is... please give us a link to an editable test sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qb5gnFOs2G-daIvpaBR4zqnbWtAZJ9zNDXUOA2ewC2k/edit?usp=sharing here thanks daniel, is there anything i can read to lean more about it?

Comment: which is the cell (or cells) that need to be conditionally formatted? with what color?  BTW: [here](https://coefficient.io/conditional-formatting-google-sheets/) you could find some usefull info.